# What are the details required to automate the download of Data products of Sentinel - 1 from Copernicus SciHub?

Tags: scientific-data, python, sentinel-spacecraft

I want to understand the file name and required parameters which describe a data product so that I can automate the download using the API provided by the [Copernicus Sci-Hub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/).

What is the pipeline of actions to download data from Sentinel 1A/B given Date, Co-ordinates etc. so that a Python Script can be written for it. What are the required libraries?

Comment: The Copernicus user manual seems to provide the first part of your question (file name and parameters) https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/6OpenSearchAPI#URI_components

Comment: If you've figured out how to proceed, consider posting an answer to your own question, which is always okay in SE, and also helpful to future readers, and maybe you pick up a little more rep too.

Comment: Will do. But, I haven't yet solved it. I almost got it. I have problem with co-ordinates format. I'll give a link to half baked solution: https://ideone.com/L5i6Ml

Comment: This is the new issue though: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29832/25043 related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use Sentinelsat, which is an open source Python library to support searching, downloading and retrieving the metadata of Sentinel satellite images from the Copernicus Open Access Hub.

It offers both an easy-to-use command line interface as well as a powerful Python API.

Sentinelsat can be installed with `pip` and is available from here: https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/

It has been integrated with GRASS GIS (open source): https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/i.sentinel.html