# What is the parameter which stays constant at a location for downloading from Sentinel Copernicus Data?

Tags: python, sentinel-spacecraft

The parameters orbitdirection, orbitnumber, platformname, productclass, producttype etc. seem to be not very useful in identifying a product in sentinel data.

I have a product targeting an area -

[image: ScreenShot of a Sentinel-1 data product meta data]

I want to download data products almost at the same location with the gap of 12 days for a year or two.

I can change data but I can't find a parameter to identify that location.

I have 2 very crude ideas.

My idea to find the intersection of data results with the sample data's polygon and find it's area and maximize it for every query which seems very complex and non-intuitive.

Time is another parameter to identify it. As satellite passes the same location almost at the same time for a given location. Make a Threshold of start time range and download whatever products I get.

Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: half baked solution: https://ideone.com/L5i6Ml

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If I understand your question correctly, you might be able to use the location search query option in the API to get content for a particular rectangle specified by the latitude and longitude of the opposite corners. From the [API docs](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/8BatchScripting#Query_via_cURL):</strike>

> -c <coordinates i.e.: lon1,lat1:lon2,lat2> : coordinates of two opposite vertices of the rectangular area of interest

**Using the Python API**

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI

api = SentinelAPI('<username>', '<password>')
products = api.query(footprint = "\"Intersects(POLYGON((-4.53 29.85, 26.75 29.85, 26.75 46.80,-4.53 46.80,-4.53 29.85)))\"")
print(products)
```

Note the escaped quotes before and after the `Intersects(...)`. This is to make sure the query matches the [necessary parameter format for text searches](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/3FullTextSearch).

Comment: I wanted to do it in Python 3. Not command line.

Comment: From the Python API documentation, it's implied you might be able to do something similar: `api.query(footprint = "intersects(POLYGON( ... ))", ...)`. Just signed up to access the API, so I'll give it a try when my credentials become valid.

Comment: It's inelegant, but there's always the `commands` module; `commands.getstatusoutput()` or just `commands.getoutput()`

Comment: @MatthewR. I tried similar things actually. Here are the errors.
      
https://imgur.com/a/XM2U9yq if I used footprint as a parameter    
    
https://imgur.com/a/XM2U9yq if I used area_relation as the parameter

Comment: I'm even trying with geojson https://imgur.com/a/xyDWiIJ but I got this error.

Comment: I had the same error, and it was solved by escaping another set of quotes around `Intersects(...)`